# Sequential Consistency in Distributed Systems

Tags: sequential, distributed-system, consistency

I am learning Sequential Consistency in Distributed Systems but just could not understand the terms explained. I would appreciate if someone can shed some light in layman's term on why (a) and (c) below are sequentially consistent and (b) is not.
Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 12):

An execution `e` of operations is sequentially consistent if and only if it can be permutated into a sequence `s` of these operations such that:

- the sequence `s` respects the program order of each process. That is, for any two operations `o1` and `o2` which are of the same process and if `o1` precedes `o2` in `e`, then `o1` should be placed before `o2` in `s`;
- in the sequence `s`, each read operation returns the value of the last preceding write operation over the same variable.

---

For (a), `s` can be：

`W(x)b [P2], R(x)b [P3], R(x)b [P4], W(x)a [P1], R(x)a [P3], R(x)a [P4]`

For (c), `s` can be:

`W(x)a [P1], R(x)a [P2], R(x)a [P3], R(x)a [P4], W(x)b [P3], R(x)b [P1], R(x)b [P2], R(x)b [P4]`

However, for (b):

- the operations `R(x)b, R(x)a` from `P3` require that `W(x)b` come before `W(x)a`
- the operations `R(x)a, R(x)b` from `P4` require that `W(x)a` come before `W(x)b`

It is impossible to construct such a sequence `s`.

Comment: Second point is a bit misleading. A read operation on the process that wrote the value should return it's written value or anything newer (as soon as it returns newer value, it can't return older values anymore). On any other processes, reads can return older values, as long as it complies with write order (it doesn't traverse time backward). So for example, in case (C), R(x) on P1 can return "a", but if it returns "b", then from that point onward, it can't return "a" anymore.

Comment: As more info, please take a look at [here](https://cs.gmu.edu/~setia/cs707/slides/consistency.pdf). Slide number 8 says: "Definition of sequential consistency says nothing about time -- **there is no reference to the most recent write operation**"

Comment: This [link](https://www.e-reading.club/chapter.php/143358/218/Tanenbaum_-_Distributed_operating_systems.html), also corroborates my comment. Specially the first figure.

Comment: @MajidAzimi Yes, it does not refer to time. However, it does refer to a total order/permutation/sequence of operations based on which the notion of "the most recent" is well-defined.

Comment: Why the operations R(x)b, R(x)a from P3 require that W(x)b come before W(x)a?

Comment: @noobcoder Cause when we read x the first time the result was b but when we read it the second time the result is a meaning there had to be a write in x that overwrote b to a